# Count items in defaultdict

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a `defaultdict`, then converted to a dictionary. Now I am looking for a way to count the items grouped by value. What i mean is:

```
dict = {1: [103], 2: [9], 3: [3, 4], 4: [103, 106], 10: [3, 4], 11: [1, 9], 28: [1]}

for key in dict.items():
    print key
```

---

```
(1, [103])
(2, [9])
(3, [3, 4])
(4, [103, 106])
(10, [3, 4])
(11, [1, 9])
(28, [1])

item : total
{4 : 2, 106 : 1} ...
```

How can i do that?

Comment: Side note: you should not call a variable `dict`, because it shadows the built-in `dict` (dictionary constructor). `my_dict` is an option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the number of occurrences of each element in the values lists, like this

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(value for values in d.itervalues() for value in values)
Counter({1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 103: 2, 9: 2, 106: 1})
```

`Counter` is a subclass of dictionary only. So, you can use it just like any other dictionary

---

The flattening of the values can be done with [`itertools.chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable), like this

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> Counter(chain.from_iterable(d.itervalues()))
Counter({1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 103: 2, 9: 2, 106: 1})
```

Comment: There is also the slightly longer but simple: `counts = Counter(); for values in d.itervalues(): counts.update(values)`.

Answer (score 0):

This is another way to do it without using anything but the basics.

```
d = {1: [103], 2: [9], 3: [3, 4], 4: [103, 106], 10: [3, 4], 11: [1, 9], 28: [1]}


answer = {} # store the counts here
for key in d:
    for value in d[key]:
        if value in answer:
            # if the key is already in the answer
            answer[value] += 1
        else:
            # if the key has never been counted before
            # then add it to the answer and set its value to 1
            answer.update({value:1}) 


for key in answer:
    print key, answer[key]
```

It prints:

```
1 2
3 2
4 2
103 2
9 2
106 1
```

Comment: I am not the original downvoter, but as a Python teacher, I would never recommend a solution that bypasses the standard library only to write something which is longer (to both write and read), and less clear.

Comment: I disagree with that. Considering the question, the user is not so advanced in python so using Counter or list comprehension or itervalues() may confuse. The code I posted is longer but more easy to grasp since it uses only the basic concepts of python. In my opinion, a beginner should not use more advanced code, even if more pythonic, without having understood the basics. In this case I think that the user is still struggling with the basics and my code could be more useful to him/her.

Comment: Yeah, we do disagree, but thank you for sharing. :) The concept behind `collections.Counter` is very simple: a beginner can understand that it's just something that counts the values that you give it, as its name indicate. I would argue that deciphering the logic of the code in your answer is harder, since it takes more time to understand. Furthermore, if you think of your answer as an example that can be followed by beginners, they will keep spending 5–10 times the normal time writing code. I would argue that this does not help beginners concentrate on the task at hand.

Comment: To summarize my point of view: it is not easier to construct a house with "simple" bare hands; using "complicated" tools like a saw and a drill is simpler.

Comment: I got your point. But again, I remember when I started, I hated list comprehension and imports.. Then when I started feeling more comfortable I began appreciating them. I guess it's personal and I bet some beginner will be glad to compare different code and make his choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
m_dict = dict
n = {}
for k, v in m_dict.iteritems():
    for j in v:
        n[j] = (n[j] + 1 if n.get(j) != None else 1)
print n
```

Result:

```
{1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 9: 2, 103: 2, 106: 1}
```

Or:

```
m_dict = dict
n = sum([v for k,v in m_dict.iteritems()], [])
c = {j : n.count(j) for j in n}
print c
```

Result:

```
{1: 2, 3: 2, 4: 2, 9: 2, 103: 2, 106: 1}
```

Comment: Your first answer is terribly complicated (see thefourtheye's answer, but even Padraic Cunningham's for how `get()` can be used). Also, your `sum()` is simply `m_dict.values()`. The second answer is inefficient: `count()` goes through `n` repeatedly, for each of its elements (quadratic time instead of the normal linear one).